# Prime generator not shows first 2 numbers

Tags: c++

I want to **generate prime numbers** to range=100,

but it shows **5, 7, 11, 15** instead of **2, 3, 5, 7,** ...

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
range = 100;

for (uint64_t i = 0; i <= range; i++) {
    for (uint64_t j = 2; j*j <= i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) break;
        else if (j + 1 > sqrt(i)) {
                std::cout << std::fixed << i << "\t";
                count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post compilable code.

Comment: 2*2 > 2 and 2*2 > 3. Totally unrelated: Look up The Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: Your loop body is only executed if `j*j <= i`.  The sqrt test inside the loop makes no sense.  Move it to outside the inner loop (but inside the outer loop), and get rid of the insane `sqrt`.  Instead you can just check if `j*j > i` upon exit from the inner loop.

Comment: @TomKarzes can you post code with your changes please? :)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Which is fortunate, since 1 isn't prime.  The first prime number is 2.

Comment: Think what happens when `i` is `2`.   The inner loop starts with `j = 2`, and `j*j` will be `4` which is greater than `i`.   So the body of the inner loop - which is the only place where `i` is printed, will never be executed.  Same happens if `i` is `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix your loop:

```
range = 100;

for (uint64_t i = 2; i <= range; i++) {
    uint64_t j;
    for (j = 2; j*j <= i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) break;
    }
    if (j*j > i) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << i << "\t";
        count++;
    }
}
```

Note that the declaration of `j` had to be moved outside of the inner loop in order for its value to be available after the loop exits.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have a nice day/night :)